# How to use CSS transitions with <text> elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a graph using svg, and want to make things looks pretty.
In my graph, I have a `<circle>` with `<text>` inside it, and the circle move around.
I used transitions to make my circle move pretty, but can't use it with `<text>` tags
 The text goes out of the circle, while the circle is moving.

What I can do so the text follow the circle element?

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/iQZL1Pb4ozY80uFsVJaQ

```js
var x = true;
var test = function() {

  var circleEl = document.getElementById('circle');

  var textEl = document.getElementById('text');

  if (x) {
    circleEl.setAttribute('cx', '400')
    textEl.setAttribute('x', '397')
    x = false
  } else {
    circleEl.setAttribute('cx', '50')
    textEl.setAttribute('x', '47')
    x = true
  }

}
```

```css
.circle-transition {
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 3s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.text-transition {
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 3s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1000px" heigth="200px">
      <circle class="circle-transition" id="circle" r="10px" cy="50" cx="50" fill="red"></circle>
      <text class="text-transition" id="text" y="55" x="47">1</text>
     </svg>

<button onclick="test()">test it!</button>
```

Comment: use javascript to animate your `text` instead of css maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that IE11 and Edge do not support CSS transforms on SVG elements.
My workaround was to use both CSS Transform and Transform attribute, that way all browsers shows the circle and text right position (IE wasn't positioning it at all), but only the animations doesn't work in IE/Edge.

```js
var x = true;
var test = function() {

  var circleEl = document.getElementById('circle');
  var textEl = document.getElementById('text');

  if (x) {
    circleEl.setAttribute('style', 'transform:translate(350px, 0px)')
    textEl.setAttribute('style', 'transform:translate(350px, 0px)')
    circleEl.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(350, 0)')
    textEl.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(350, 0)')
    x = false
  } else {
    circleEl.setAttribute('style', 'transform:translate(0px, 0px)')
    textEl.setAttribute('style', 'transform:translate(0px, 0px)')
    circleEl.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')
    textEl.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')
    x = true
  }

}
```

```css
.circle-transition {
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 3s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.text-transition {
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 3s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1000px" heigth="200px">
      <circle class="circle-transition" id="circle" r="10px" cy="50" cx="50" fill="red" style="transform: translate(0,0)" transform="translate(0, 0)"></circle>
      <text class="text-transition" id="text" y="55" x="47" style="transform:translate(0,0)" transform="translate(0, 0)">1</text>
     </svg>

<button onclick="test()">test it!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a bit cautious about using [SVG presentation attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html#PresentationAttributes) and animating them with CSS. For example, your problem description only applies to Chrome. In Firefox, both the circle and the text jump.

Best to use only CSS style properties, in this case `transform`. In addition, you can group elements together so that only one animation is needed:

```js
var x = true;
var test = function() {

  var groupEl = document.getElementById('group');

  if (x) {
    groupEl.setAttribute('style', 'transform:translate(350px)')
    x = false
  } else {
    groupEl.setAttribute('style', 'transform:translate(0px)')
    x = true
  }

}
```

```css
.group-transition {
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 3s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1000px" heigth="200px">
     <g id="group" class="group-transition" style="transform:translate(0px)">
      <circle id="circle" r="10px" cy="50" cx="50" fill="red"></circle>
      <text id="text" y="55" x="47">1</text>
    </g>
</svg>

<button onclick="test()">test it!</button>
```

Comment: Seems so. [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) says IE11 and Edge do not support CSS transforms on SVG elements, and using the presentation attribute gets you back to square one. The next fallback would be to use an isolated svg element that consists only of your circle+text and move it around in its entirety in the html document.